# How to create Unix timestamp from own date string just by Typoscript?

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript

I'm looking for the possibility to convert my own datetime string, e.g., "12:55 23-04-2013" to standard Unix timestamp 1366721700 (not opposite way) just by pure Typoscript.

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://docs.typo3.org/TYPO3/TyposcriptSyntaxReference/). Figure out if it is even possible. If it is then try to figure it out. If you get stuck then explain what you have tried and ask a question.

Comment: I think you need a userFunc for that. Here's an old tutorial:

http://www.typo3forum.net/forum/powermail/36102-powermail-datum-timestamp-powermail_frontend-datum.html